# OpenSSL path that doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, openssl, node-gyp

When I try `node-gyp configure`

- It tells me I'm using node-gyp@7.1.2, node@15.0.1, Python 2.7.15,
- It tells me it's getting https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.0.1/node-v15.0.1-headers.tar.gz
- but then I get an error of `Error: write EPROTO 9620:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:`

Now, I'm in a company that takes its security very seriously and I can understand if I'm not allowed to
download from nodejs.org, maybe that's related, but the especially strange thing about this is that **folder `c:\ws\` doesn't exist**! At first I created my workspace to be in C:\ws, but then realized that anyone who signs into the PC would have access, so I abandoned that and started using a workspace under %USERPROFILE% instead. Maybe I just need to blow away all of node and npm and start over? As awful as that might be, at this point I would shrug, say #Thanks2020, and do it gladly, but I first want to know I'm not missing something.

I have tried:

- Searching my entire C drive for file names containing "openssl" and found no results
- Searching my registry for "deps" and "openssl" and found no results
- Searching all files in %USERPROFILE% and several other places for OpenSSL or "\WS" and found no results.
- Trying it again, because hey, computers can be fickle like that and I'm out of ideas, but the issue is consistent.
- Seeing that my "Control Panel \ User Accounts \ Credential Manager" has no windows credentials for nodejs.org, and no web credentials at all.

Why is it looking in c:\ws\ ? Heck, why is it looking for *anything*? What's going on? Is this even a node-gyp thing or should I be giving this question a different tag?

Comment: That file/path is not being accessed in any way. It is the **source file (path)name** (and line number) that was compiled on some other system in the past to produce the OpenSSL binary which is being run, by something; I can't tell from this if it's nodejs, python, or something else doing the attempted connection.

Comment: I don't remember how I resolved this, but for others my advice is to run `git config --get-all --global http.sslBackend` to confirm what's going on, and make sure your credentials manager is clean.

Comment: I've faced the same problem, but with "npm install". It seems like your company is blocking content that does not fit some set of security criteria (restricted set of protocols (tlsv1, tlsv2..), restricted set of sites..). The solution for me was to run the same command "npm install" but with a privileged user (admin account). You gonna need to check with your IT guys.
Read more: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2908#issuecomment-671877956